# Changing an NSView Transform

Tags: swift, macos, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to move, resize, and rotate an NSView based on incoming data from a third party source.

I have tried using the layer's transform, but for some reason the view snaps back to its original state as soon as data stops coming in (and flickers in between).

Here's what I'm doing:

```
class BlueView: NSView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.wantsLayer = true
        Swift.print("hey")
    }
}
```

And to change the view:

```
blueView?.layer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(100, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

I'm probably missing a step, but I can only find examples about animation, which I don't need.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this view under the influence of auto layout? Auto layout and transform changes of this sort are enemies of one another.

Comment: My other question is this: Is the code that applies the transformations in a completion block that's running on a background thread? That, like all UI changes, should be done on the main thread.

Comment: @matt Just tried disabling autolayout, no luck... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @DuncanC Nope, it's just a regular function. I tried to force the main thread just in case but no luck there either. Thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, the example line in your question does not make sense: `CATransform3DMakeRotation(100, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. The angle is expressed in radians, not degrees. The value 100 is not any even fraction of pi. It represents almost 16 full rotations from 0. You probably need to convert degrees to radians. (This isn't the cause of your problem but still...)

Comment: @DuncanC Good catch, 100 is just a random value to try out. The input variable is already in radians, and I decided to just throw that in there to see if it even rotates any amount, while avoiding any other point of failure.

Comment: The value 100 is quite close to 16 full revolutions. You might not see the difference. The value pi/2 is good for testing (1/4 turn), although for non-square images it can cause layout problems. Using pi will turn the image upside-down, but if it's axially symmetrical you won't see a change.